# Calling a function with its previous return value as an argument in a while loop in Python

Tags: python

I need to keep calling the following function with its previous return value as an argument in a while loop:

```
def announce_lead_changes(last_leader=None):
    """Return a commentary function that announces lead changes.

    >>> f0 = announce_lead_changes()
    >>> f1 = f0(5, 0)
    Player 0 takes the lead by 5
    >>> f2 = f1(5, 12)
    Player 1 takes the lead by 7
    >>> f3 = f2(8, 12)
    >>> f4 = f3(8, 13)
    >>> f5 = f4(15, 13)
    Player 0 takes the lead by 2
    """
    def say(score0, score1):
        if score0 > score1:
            leader = 0
        elif score1 > score0:
            leader = 1
        else:
            leader = None
        if leader != None and leader != last_leader:
            print('Player', leader, 'takes the lead by', abs(score0 - score1))
        return announce_lead_changes(leader)
    return say
```

I understand how the doctest works but how do I implement this in a while loop? I tried the following but it keeps on passing the default argument throughout loop:

```
commentary = both(say_scores, announce_lead_changes())
while
    ...
    commentary(score0, score1)
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the testing framework

Comment: What is ``both``?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain. Both is just a higher-order function to execute two functions that are passed as arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `commentary` for each iteration in the while loop. Try :

```
commentary = both(say_scores, announce_lead_changes())
while
    ...
    commentary = commentary(score0, score1)
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of this. It works. Thank you so much!!!